# Passing flatlist render "Item" to a function. React Native (kinda a js question)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Right now I have a flatlist that contains a bunch of firebase objects (books), when one of the book are clicked, I want to return a page with more data about that specific book. Right now each book it an object, where title is one of the values, this is what is shown on the flatlist. I want to be able to show all of the other object attributes when the new detailed page is opened. If there is a better way of doing this, let me know but this is the logic that I was trying to go with.

```
(this is in the flatlist)
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={bookOnPressHandler} activeOpacity={0.9} style={styles.flatListStyle}>
                            <View>

                                <Text>{item.title}</Text>

                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                />
```

then the handler:

```
    const bookOnPressHandler = (item) => {
        //this holds the title of the book
        title = item.title
        console.log(title)
        navigation.navigate('booknotes')
    }
```

I obviously need to pass item into the function, what it is right now wont work. How would I get access to "Item" in the function? once I set the item = to something, I can use it on the new page.

I feel like there is a better method than this and that this might even not work? I know this is a common thing to do in apps, all help is really appreciated. Also sorry if its obvious, Im pretty new to this language and framework!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have access to the required `object` that is to be passed to the next screen, it's very easy, you can pass it along with the navigation object as a `route` param.

It's always good to isolate the `prop` functions to separate functions to avoid unnecessary re-render of the component.

Here is an example.

```js
 <FlatList
        ref={ref}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        numColumns={2}
        data={exploreData}
        initialNumToRender={2}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.id.toString()}
        })}
      />
```

Here is the `renderItem` function:

```js
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  const handleOnPress = () => navigation.navigate("Profile", { item });
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={handleOnPress}
    >
      <ImageBackground
        source={{ uri: img }}
        style={styles.image}
        imageStyle={styles.background}
      />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
```

```js
//Profile Screen
const Profile = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { item } = route.params;
  console.log(item);
};
```

Comment: another quick basic question.. What would this look like on the page that's receiving "Item"?

Comment: Guess this is why they say to learn the language before jumping into a framework. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could say that, but sometimes reverse works too. It worked for me :)